# Calculating of genus of a curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, computer-science, finite-fields, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$ in projective plane. So $C$ can be done as zeroes of some gomogeneous  polynomial $\in \mathbb{F}_q[x,y,z]$ with degree $n$.
Whether is there algorithm which is polynomial time in $n$ that calculate arithmetic genus of $C$?

Comment: Indeed: as long as the curve $C$ is smooth, the genus only depends on the degree of the defining homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: yes, curve can be non-smooth

Comment: Then what genus are you talking about? If the curve is not smooth, the arithmetic genus and the geometric genus are different.

Comment: Oh, sorry I mean the arithmetic genus

Answer (score 4):

Since you have clarified your question, I can now answer.

The arithmetic genus depends only on the degree of $C$ and the dimension of the projective space it is embedded in.

In fact, the arithmetic genus is **defined** as 
$$
1-P_C(0),
$$
where $P_C(t)$ is the Hilbert polynomial of $C$.

But the Hilbert polynomial of a curve og degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^2$ can be computed by the exact sequence 
$$
0 \to \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^2} (-d) \to \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^2} \to \mathscr O_C\to 0.
$$

By additivity of exact sequences, we have
$$
P_C(t) = \binom{t+2}{2} -\binom{t-d+2}{2} = td -\frac 12 d^2+\frac 32 d.
$$

Thus, we see that the arithmetic genus of **any** degree $d$ curve (singular, reducible...) is given by
$$
1+\frac 12 d^2 -\frac 32 d = \frac{(d-2)(d-1)}{2}.
$$

In particular, a curve of degree $3$ have arithmetic genus $1$.

Comment: It follows from what you are saying that the arithmetic genus of any degree d planar projective curve is a birational invariant, am I correct?

Comment: @kindasorta Yes, I think so. This shows that the arithmetic genus depends only on the degree of the curve, and the degree is indeed a birational invariant.

Comment: I am slightly confused now, as there is a theorem which states that the arithmetic genus equals the geometric genus in case the curve is smooth, however, as there are curves of the same degree that are smooth and not smooth, it seems to me that these curves should either have a different arithmetic genus or a geometric genus. However, as it is stated in Wikipedia that the geometric genus is a birational invariant, I would guess that the arithmetic genus is different for singular curves. Am I missing on something?

Comment: @kindasorta I'm kinda rusty on this topic, but my understanding is that "birational invariance" only is about smooth curves. The geometric and arithmetic genus are indeed different for smooth/singular curves.